# Is there a native C++ alternative to the C's "memcmp"?

Tags: c++, boost

Does C++ or Boost has a function that compares two blocks of memory just like the C's memcmp?

I tried Google but I only got the "memcmp" function.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use `memcmp` in C++ as well. It is native in C++ too.

All that you need to do is, include `<cstring>` and then use fully-qualified name [`std::memcmp`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/memcmp/) instead of `memcmp`. It is because it is in `std` namespace, like every other standard library functions and classes.

Comment: I know that, but I am asking about something that is C++ only!!

Comment: @MIH1406: Means which is not `memcmp` but does exactly the same thing? Why do you think C++ would provide another function, which does  *exactly* the same thing as `memcmp` does? C++ avoids duplication. And what is wrong with using `std::memcmp`?

Comment: I do not want to use C's stuff. I need something only for C++.

Comment: @MIH1406: `std::memcmp` is not only C's stuff. It is in both languages. Do you have `int main(){}` in your program? Is it C's stuff too?

Comment: @MIH1406: Justify your goals, please. Whats wrong with using "C's stuff"? Just sounds like you're making up rules of the sake of having rules.

Comment: @Nawaz, GMan: Do you mean that <cstdio> <cstdlib> <cstring> are included in the C++ standards? Are all of them included in the "libstdc++"?
Forgive my "Ignorance" in C++

Comment: @MIH1406: yes. All of them are included in C++ Standard. They are as much C++, as they are C.

Comment: @GManNickG A legitimate, albeit cosmetical reason: Unlike C, C++ requires casts from pointer to void pointer to be explicit. Which undermines the use of void pointer in those mem* functions, and make their use *look* bad, in case someone on your team has pointy fingers.

Comment: @user2394284 No that's not correct. Cast *from* `T*` *to* `void*` is not explicit in C++. `int i = 42; void* p = &i;` works as-is. Similarly `memcmp(&a, &b, sizeof(a));` also works as-is. (You do have to match cv-qualifiers).

Answer (score 32):

If you want a function which can handle both pointers and STL iterators take a look at [`std::equal`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/equal) in `<algorithm>`.

I'd consider `std::equal` to be the C++ way of doing `std::memcmp` (which is indeed still C++, but `std::memcmp` doesn't handle iterator objects).

---

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int 
main (int argc, char *argv[])
{   
  int  a1[] = {1,2,3,4};
  int  a2[] = {1,9,3,5};

  int * p1  = new int[4];

  std::vector<int> vec (a2, a2+4);


  *(p1++) = 1; *(p1++) = 2;
  *(p1++) = 3; *(p1++) = 4;

  p1 -= 4;


  if (std::equal (a1, a1+4, p1)) {
    std::cout << "memory of p1 == memory of a1\n";
  }   

  if (std::equal (vec.begin (), vec.end (), p1) == false) {
    std::cout << "memory of p1 != memory of vec\n";
  }   
}
```

output

```
memory of p1 == memory of a1
memory of p1 != memory of vec
```

Comment: I think the key difference is that memcmp compares blocks of bytes, whereas equal compares ranges of objects based on however equality is defined for the objects. - An example, memcmp evaluating padding bytes which can be filled with arbitrary garbage: http://ideone.com/aEdGa

Comment: @UncleBens Yes, there are differences and most people will bring up that std::memcmp is most often optimized for greater speed, though std::equal might (and often have) template specializations to have the same performance when dealing with native types.

Comment: @UncleBens I'm sure this wasn't your point, but to remind others; comparing the raw memory of objects (that often include padding) is not at all recommended. Since we are writing C++, define your own `operator==` instead

Comment: @refp: I disagree with this "*I'd consider std::equal to be the c++ way of doing std::memcmp*", because `std::equal` and `std::memcmp` are two different functionalities, they do two different sort of things; for few cases, they might *appear* to be doing the same thing, but that isn't true for all cases. Another thing is that `std::equal` is slower than `std::memcmp`, for the latter compares blocks of bytes and it is highly optimized.

Comment: @Nawaz The exact implementation of std::memcmp is not defined by the standard. There is nothing saying that std::equal doesn't compare data pointed to by `char*` (or whatever) the same way and, as said in a previous comment, it may have template specializations to increase performance for different types of objects.

Comment: @Nawaz http://ppst.me/xoS3vw there you can find the implementation of std::equal from libstdc++-v3, as you see there is an alternative version which uses `__builtin_memcmp`, which you can look up if you want to.

Comment: @refp: That is good. But still they are different functionality. Because `std::equal` can return  either `true` or `false`, to indicate equality or inequality, respectively. But `std::memcmp` can return `-ve`, `0` and `+ve` to indicate less-than,  equality, greater-than, respectively.

Comment: @Nawaz Yes, that is a difference between the two where I have no arguments to support my point that they are "equivalent", though now that I think about it there are other functions in the STL that acts more like std::memcmp (with a bit of hack, that is). Thanks for your feedback!

Answer (score 2):

`memcmp` is a part of C++ standard library and available in `<cstring>`. Since your requirement is to compare 2 blocks of memory (dealing with raw memory), you have to use `memcmp` or other functions in  library.

If you don't want to deal with memory, then use C++ containers to abstract memory management. Then you would be dealing with objects!

Answer (score 1):

Use memcmp. It's a perfectly legitimate C++ function.

Answer (score 1):

memcmp is part of the C++ standard library (by inclusion).